# How to have sheets open automatically in a excel work book

Tags: excel

I have a work book with twelve sheets named January to December
when I open the book it must open at the current months sheet even if the book has not been opened for a few months
tx

Answer (score 1):

Resave your workbook as a macro enabled workbook (.xlsm)

Press ALT+ F11 to enter the VBA Editor.

In the Project Explorer on the left,double click on "This Workbook" which is a child of your workbook.

Add the following code on the right and then press save.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()

   ThisWorkbook.Sheets(MonthName(Month(Date))).Activate

End Sub
```